# Inverse relation graphical shape

Tags: graphing-functions, relations, inverse-function-theorem

I have a few points among two quantities which are inversely related. The points are $(0,20), (1,19)$ and $(5,15)$. I have drawn these points in Matlab but it gives me an inverted triangle which isn't present in the inverse relationship among the two quantities.  Clearly stated, if I have two quantities and they are inversely related, what shape should it show me if I were given only three points?  Please help me.

Comment: Strange, that looks like my editing word for word.   Is there a software problem?

Answer (score 0):

Any three points when plotted on a plane will appear as a triangle.
Inversely related quanties will appear somewhat like the curve y = 1/x.
Points should appear more or less along such a curve.  It is up to you to decide, given three points, how the curve may lie.  The points will appear as a broken line.  Which side of the inverted triangle to remove will require some thought.

Expecting a quick answer from a computer is often a waste of time.